# DigitalOcean Load Balancer and Nginx droplet returns 503

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I have a load balancer set with the following forwarding rule

HTTPS:443 -> HTTPS:443 with a certificate I am not using Passthrough

[forwarding rules and health checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC3qw.png)

this load balancer has two droplets with Nginx setup  with an SSL certificate when I try to access the domain name I get a 503 service Unavailable although it was working fine before the Load balancer

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: What kind of caching have you configured that still warrants the need to set up a load balancer?

Comment: do you see the nginx log?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I'm facing the same issue